# update JsObject value for a specific key

Tags: scala, play-json

lets say I have this simple json as JsObject:

```
val simpleJson = Json.parse("""{
                       "name" : "Watership Down"
                       }""".stripMargin).as[JsObject]
```

and I want to change the "name" value, how would I do that on JsObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
simpleJson ++ JsObject(Map("name": JsString("Spaceship Up")))
```

`++` merges two `JsObject`s, with the right-hand-side taking precedence.

Answer (score 1):

As @Levi Ramsey said, just without the Play Json wrappers:

```
simpleJson ++ Json.obj("name" -> "Spaceship Up");
```

From Play `2.4.X` you can use `+`:

```
simpleJson + ("name" -> "Spaceship Up");
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bvAXZw8TSTetuWJcMeQU0Q